# Field Update on Button click Using JavaScript

Tags: apex, javascript

My field is not getting updated for Owner Id on Case Object

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}'; 
var orgId = '{!Case.Original_Case_Owner__c}'; 
caseObj.Status = 'In Progress'; 
caseObj.RecordType = 'L2';

var records = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from User Where Name = '{!Case.Original_Case_Owner__c}'");
var records1 = records.getArray('records');
var userId = ''; 
for(var i=0;i<records1.length;i++)
{ userId = records1[i].Id; } 
caseObj.OwnerId= userId ; 

var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: What is the data type of Original_Case_Owner__c, lookup to user or text?

Comment: It is a text field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
caseObj.Id = '{!Case.Id}'; 

var caseRecords = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from User Where Name = '{!Case.Original_Case_Owner__c}'");

var records = caseRecords.getArray("records");

caseObj.OwnerId = records[0].Id;
sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);

window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me so I think you probably have a validation rule preventing the update on the case. It could also be a trigger or a workflow rule interfering with this. Can you take a look at the logs?

Comment: Sorry that was wrong . I have  edited it. But it's still not working.

Comment: is the query returning any results?

Comment: I am not getting even error for the same.

Comment: The Query returning Id of the user in alert. But it is not getting updated.

Comment: I have updated my answer.